# Log4j2 configuration in java or xml?

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to save logs on the server and the path to the save location will be downloaded from the database. I know that there will be a delay because the logs are start first  and then the database. But if there will be a delay, I can do this in the xml or I must do in Java code?

Comment: It's recommended to configure log4j2 with xml and you can use `JDBCAppender` to directly log to a database. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender

Comment: I do not want to save logs in the database, I only download the path to sace logs from the database where the log should be saved